# how to retrieve values ​from html in class li, one by one?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

how to fetch values ​​from html in li class, one by one? according to the html value, I tried always fail, is there any solution?

---

my js:

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $(".list-group-item").click(function() {
     var nilai = $(".mb-25").text();
      alert(nilai);
            })
         
          });
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
   <ul class="list-group">
   <li class="list-group-item"><h5 class="mb-25">Cras justo odio</h5></li>
  <li class="list-group-item"><h5 class="mb-25">Dapibus ac facilisis in</h5></li>
  <li class="list-group-item"><h5 class="mb-25">Morbi leo risus</h5></li>
  <li class="list-group-item"><h5 class="mb-25">Porta ac consectetur ac</h5></li>
  <li class="list-group-item"><h5 class="mb-25">Vestibulum at eros</h5></li>
</ul>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xpfasq0v/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to select the element inside the one you clicked

```
var nilai = $(this).find(".mb-25").text();
```

```js
$(".list-group").on("click", "li", function () {
  var nilai = $(this).find(".mb-25").text();
  console.log(nilai);
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
   <ul class="list-group">
   <li class="list-group-item"><h5 class="mb-25">Cras justo odio</h5></li>
  <li class="list-group-item"><h5 class="mb-25">Dapibus ac facilisis in</h5></li>
  <li class="list-group-item"><h5 class="mb-25">Morbi leo risus</h5></li>
  <li class="list-group-item"><h5 class="mb-25">Porta ac consectetur ac</h5></li>
  <li class="list-group-item"><h5 class="mb-25">Vestibulum at eros</h5></li>
</ul>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```